# Spinner working on emulator(genymotion) but not on mobile

Tags: android, spinner

I'm developing an Android application that uses a spinner in one of its fragments.
It works fine onemulator (API 21), but when I tried to use on my mobile (API 24 and 21), the spinner looks like a blank list.

Here is the code:

```
ArrayList<String> tags_array = getArrayList();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, tags_array);

    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);


    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

            mParam2 = tags_hash.get(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());                
            new getPostsFiltradosAsync().execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });
```

[Mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRK9J.png)

[Emulator version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYZRL.png)

Does anybody know what is causing this?
Thank you.

**EDIT: ON THE EMULATOR FOR API'S 23 AND 24 DOESN'T WORK EITHER, SO THE PROBLEM IS PROBABLY IN THE ANDROID VERSIONS, NOT SURE WHY YET.
I WILL TRY TO CREATE A CUSTOM SPINNER TO SEE IF WORKS.**

Comment: I can not see the difference in images you posted.

Comment: Sorry. I upload the same image. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, API's 23 and 24 don't show spinner correctly  using the Adapter bellow:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, tags_array);
```

I worked arround the issue by creating a new adapter from the class bellow:

```
class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;

ArrayList<String> tagsNames;
LayoutInflater inflter;

public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context applicationContext, ArrayList<String> tagsNames) {
    this.context = applicationContext;
    this.tagsNames = tagsNames;
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tagsNames.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.spinner_layout, null);
    TextView tag_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tag_name);
    tag_name.setText(tagsNames.get(i));
    return view;
}
```

}

It worked fine.
Thank you for the help.